# Symfony2 - Embedded forms wipe child data

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

Yet another continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15977529/399584) and [also this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16016482/399584):

So, I'm able to initially show a form that contains a BlogPost and it's associated Comments.  The problem is, if I edit some BlogPost info and save, it wipes out *all* of my Comments, regardless of whether or not they're related to *that* BlogPost.  Not good.

Most of my relevant code is in the second link above, so I won't repeat it here.  I will, however, add what's in my controller and view.

Controller:

```
public function EditBlogAction($id)
{
    $request = $this->get('request');
    $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $blogPost = $em->getRepository('Acme\SiteBundle\Entity\BlogPost')->find($id);

    $comments = $blogPost->getComments();

    $form = $this->createForm(new BlogPostType(), $blogPost);

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bind($request);

        foreach ($comments as $comment) {
            $em->persist($comment);
        }
        $em->persist($blogPost);

        $em->flush();
        $em->clear();
    }

    return $this->render('SiteBundle:Site:editblog.html.twig',array('blogpost' => $blogPost, 'form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

editblog.html.twig:

```
<form action='{{ path('_admin_blog_edit', { 'id':blogpost.getId }) }}' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form_widget(form.title) }}

    {# other blog post fields #}

    {% for comment in form.comments %}
        {{ comment.commentBody }}
    {% endfor %}
<input type="submit" />
```

I can't see why saving BlogPost info would wipe any Comments, let alone Comments not belonging to that particular post.

Comment: From your second post, I saw that you use `cascade={"all"},orphanRemoval=true` on the relation with `Comment`. what if you remove the `$em->persist($comment)` in your controller and replace `cascade={"all"}` with `cascade={"persist"}`?

Comment: Awesome, that did it!  Make your comment an answer and I'll upvote/mark as solved

Comment: Before I post an answer, what if you keep `cascade={"all"}`?

Comment: `Cascade={'all'}` works, too, so it looks like it was a matter of me trying to persist the comments in a loop rather than just persisting the blog post and letting the cascade handle the rest.

Comment: Ok I have added my answer. Anyway, try to use `cascade={"all"}` with moderation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `cascade={"all"}` on the `OneToMany` relationship between `Comment` and `BlogPost`.

You don't need to manually `persist` the comments posted with your blog post, so you can remove the following code from your controller (in `EditBlogAction()`):

```
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
  $em->persist($comment);
}
```

Doctrine documentation on the subject: https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html?highlight=Transitive%20Persistence#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations